# AWS CLI- What is the syntax for assigning multiple values on a parameter

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

For example, I have this CF template that ask for these parameters

```
----- cftemplate.yaml -----
...
Parameters:
  **Subnet:
    Description: Subnet for the Instance
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id'
  SecurityGroups: 
    Description: Security Group for Instance
    Type: 'List<AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id>'**
...
Resources:
 EC2Instance:
   Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
   Properties:
...
    **SubnetId: !Ref Subnet
    SecurityGroupIds: !Ref SecurityGroups**
...
----- cftemplate.yaml -----
```

For me to deploy the stack, I use this command:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name StackName --template-body file://cftemplate.yaml --parameters file://params.json
```

Where params.json contains:

```
----- params.json ----- 
[
        {
            "ParameterKey":"Subnet",
            "ParameterValue":"subnet-11111111"
        },
        {
            "ParameterKey":"SecurityGroups",
            "ParameterValue":"sg-111111111",
            "ParameterValue":"sg-222222222"
        } 
]
----- params.json -----
```

Now, my goal is to eliminate the use of .json file. Does anyone know the shorthand syntax of the command that should achieve the same effect as above command? Can't seem to find this on the documentations online. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The command line equivalent would be (little re-formatted for clarify):

```
aws cloudformation create-stack \
    --stack-name StackName \
    --template-body file://cftemplate.yaml \
    --parameters ParameterKey=Subnet,ParameterValue=subnet-11111111 ParameterKey=SecurityGroups,ParameterValue=sg-111111111\\,sg-222222222
```

In the above attention to spaces and commas are important.

I **verified** the command using my own parameters and my sandbox account:

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name StackName --template-body file://instance.yaml --parameters ParameterKey=Subnet,ParameterValue=subnet-0ae6ce0f9bbf52251 ParameterKey=SecurityGroups,ParameterValue=sg-06d2a3e9c8aa99620\\,sg-004d23d188ec1146f
```

which is correct and results in starting the process of deploying the stack:

```
{
    "StackId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:xxxxxx:stack/StackName/61fbacd0-d3b0-11ea-970a-0ad23187ddb2"
}
```

Comment: @darren Hi. Not sure what do you mean?

Comment: Using the command:
`aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name StackName --template-body file://cftemplate.yaml --parameters ParameterKey=Subnet,ParameterValue=subnet-11111111 ParameterKey=SecurityGroups,ParameterValue=sg-111111111,sg-222222222`

Will result to this:
`Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Parameters[4].ParameterValue, value: ['sg-111111111', 'sg-222222222'], type: <class 'list'>, valid types: <class 'str'>`

Still, I think that we just need to find the correct syntax for this.

Comment: @darren The command works. I verified it using my own data as shown in the updated answer. There are no issues with data types. Thus the problems you are experiencing must be caused by other factors.

Comment: Depending upon OS, you _might_ need to put parameters in single quotes or double quotes.

Comment: @Marcin Cool!!! Your command works! Just had a mistake on my first test 'cause I'm using a lot of parameters. Thanks a lot for your replication. Kudos!!

Comment: Also found out that this syntax is also accepted:      `aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name StackName --template-body file://cftemplate.yaml --parameters ParameterKey=Subnet,ParameterValue=subnet-11111111 ParameterKey=SecurityGroups,ParameterValue='sg-111111111,sg-222222222'
`

Answer (score 1):

you might want to take a look at the rain cli. It's developed but someone from the cloudformation team and it's much better than the aws cli.

https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/rain

Comment: This made deploying stacks insanely easier.

Answer (score 0):

From the cli documentation,

```
$ aws cloudformation create-stack help

...

"--parameters" (list)

   A list of "Parameter" structures that specify input parameters for
   the stack. For more information, see the Parameter data type.

Shorthand Syntax:

   ParameterKey=string,ParameterValue=string,UsePreviousValue=boolean,ResolvedValue=string ...

JSON Syntax:

   [
     {
       "ParameterKey": "string",
       "ParameterValue": "string",
       "UsePreviousValue": true|false,
       "ResolvedValue": "string"
     }
     ...
   ]

...
```

where the list elements are separated by space.